# ¿Por que no esta ejecutandose el while en mi codigo?

Tags: python, while

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio basico en python dado que estoy aprendiendo. Al usar la funcion while no estoy logrando que me siga el bucle. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
peso=int(input("Ingrese peso de persona: "))
edad=int(input("Ingrese edad de persona: "))
niños=0
jovenes=0
adultos=0
viejos=0
continuar=1
while continuar==1:
    if edad <=12:
        print("Categoria Niños")
    elif edad <=29:
        print("Categoria Jovenes")
    elif edad <=59:
        print("Categoria Adultos")
    elif edad >60:
        print("Categoria Viejos")
    continuar=input("Desea continuar? [1] si [0] no: ")

    
print("---FIN---")
```

Por que motivo al dar en la variable continuar = 1 me da el print (FIN) y no vuelve nuevamente a consultarme los datos del inicio? que es lo que esta mal en mi sentencia?

Gracias

Comment: Tu codigo funciona, sin embargo tu error esta en la variable `continuar` que tiene el input. Este debe ser convertido a entero con `int()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la línea que dice:

```py
continuar=input("Desea continuar? [1] si [0] no: ")
```

por:

```py
continuar = int(input("Desea continuar? [1] si [0] no: "))
```

Así te aseguras que lo que leas sea convertido en entero, ya que esa es la comparación que estás haciendo (con enteros). Le agregué espacios entre el signo `=` nada más para que se vea más legible.

Comment: Sería bueno que también se agregue un bloque `try/except` en caso el usuario ingrese algo que no pueda ser convertido a número en base 10(decimal)

Comment: O más fácil aún, cambiar el `while` por `while continuar=="1"`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, efectivamente con el cambio del int en el continuar el bucle se realiza, sin embargo veo que hay algo mas que me esta fallando, ya que cuando le doy "1" para que me vuelva a pedir los datos del inicio, solamente me esta respondiendo con el "Desea continuar? " sin volverme a pedir los datos de peso y edad que le solicitaba al principio del codigo.

Comment: Ya vi mi error, el while solo ejecuta esa porcion del codigo que esta despues de. Lo que es anterior lo pasa por alto. Ya pase las variables que tenia antes al despues del while y me funciona. Muchas gracias